# Dynamic import is not working in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, dynamic-import

I'm trying to import the module dynamically but It's failing for no reason

```
 import('../Util/Cache/xxx.js').then((module) => {
      console.log('module', module);
    })
```

above one is working.

```
const path = `../Util/Cache/${fileName}`;
    import(path).then((module) => {
      console.log('module', module);
    })
```

This one is not working.

```
fileName is xxx.js
```

Comment: check value of  `fileName`

Comment: fileName is xxx.js

Comment: Its working. Check the console - https://codesandbox.io/embed/adoring-roentgen-nvluc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark